# Permissibility of listening to the audios relating to sexual intercourse

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, sex, zina

I understand, that watching porn is a big sin and so is listening to them given they both involve the zina of the eyes and ears, where one looks or hears lustful content of individuals who are not permissible for them.

However, my question concerns listening to audios that are not sex, but relating to it. As in, not listening to the moans and groans of impermissible individuals during sex but rather sound that is created upon sex such as the slapping of the bare skins or the friction of sound caused by saliva, sound of rubbing genitalia. AGAIN, given there's no lustful voice, sexual moans/groans or anything sexual interms of sound of an individual.

Honestly, this may come as a very strange question. But, I have been working on something that requires me to listen to these sex related sound and all I am asking whether they are permissible to listen or not, even if the sexual sound of non-mahrams are out of the equation altogether.

Any response will be well appreciated.